# Add url link to checkboxGroupInput inputID

Tags: r, shiny

I have a checkboxGroupInput in my UI that is filled automatically with a list. I just want to add a url link that points to the method definition.
In this case i'm using a permanova so the user can select different variables from the list. I just want to be able to click on the checkboxGroupinput title and link to the paper below. Is that possible.

```
checkboxGroupInput("permacomparisons" ,label="Select metadata",
        choices = smetadatapm,selected=smetadatapm)
```

Link to the paper describing the method:

```
  https://esajournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1890/12-2010.1
```

I havd tried adding the link in the inputID as follows:

```
checkboxGroupInput("permacomparisons <a href=http... > link</a>),label="Select metadata",
        choices = smetadatapm,selected=smetadatapm)
but doesnt work.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an HTML workaround I hope it help

```
checkboxGroupInput("permacomparisons",label=HTML('<p>Select metadata <a href=https://esajournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1890/12-2010.1>permacomparisons</a></p>'),choices = colnames(mtcars))
```